# Why do community managers have more accounts (121) than Community ♦ (106)

Tags: support, community-user, community-managers

I noticed that community managers have more accounts than Community ♦, for example

- [Anna Lear ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/anna-lear)
- [Shog9 ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9)
- [Jaydles ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147336/jaydles)
- [Tim Post ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post)

So, somewhere (15 sites!) there is no Community ♦, who

> Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
>   Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
>   Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
>   Own suggested edits from anonymous users
>   Remove abandoned questions

?

Comment: @Tim nice find!